# how can I get the hex value of color when I change its opacity

Tags: javascript, reactjs, color-picker

what my task is I need a hex value in TextFiled according to changing **opacity** of that color I added a slider for **opacity** when the slider changes at the same time that color hex value also needs to change in TextFiled according to that color opacity, right now only the color box getting change according to opacity but I also need that color hex value also to change that I am showing in picked color refer CodeSandbox link.

```
  const [newHexCodes, setNewHexCodes] = React.useState([]);
  const [opacity, setOpacity] = React.useState([]);
  const settingForm = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      hexValue: "#272d85",
      opacityValue: ""
    },
    validationSchema: settingFormSchema,
    onSubmit: (values) => {
      setNewHexCodes([values.hexValue, ...newHexCodes]);
      setOpacity([values.opacityValue, ...opacity]);
    }
  });
  const updateSlider = (event, newValue) => {
    settingForm.setFieldValue("opacityValue", newValue);
  };
  return (
       <Card>
      <CardContent sx={{ pl: 4, mt: 2 }}>
        <Grid
          container
          justifyContent="space-between"
          alignItems="center"
          spacing={2}
        >
          <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={4}>
            <Box
              display="flex"
              justifyContent="space-between"
              alignItems="center"
              flexWrap="wrap"
              gap={1}
            >
              <Box>
                <Typography variant="subtitle2" noWrap>
                  Hex Value
                </Typography>
              </Box>
              <Box>
                <TextField
                  size="small"
                  variant="outlined"
                  fullWidth
                  required
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Enter Hex value"
                  name="hexValue"
                  {...settingForm.getFieldProps("hexValue")}
                  helperText={
                    settingForm?.touched?.hexValue &&
                    settingForm?.errors?.hexValue
                  }
                  error={Boolean(
                    settingForm?.touched?.hexValue &&
                      settingForm?.errors?.hexValue
                  )}
                />
              </Box>
              <Box>
                <Box
                  display="flex"
                  justifyContent="center"
                  component="span"
                  sx={{
                    backgroundColor: settingForm.values.hexValue,
                    opacity: settingForm.values.opacityValue,
                    width: "60px",
                    height: "35px"
                  }}
                />
              </Box>
            </Box>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={4}>
            <Box
              display="flex"
              justifyContent="space-evenly"
              alignItems="center"
              gap={2}
            >
              <LightModeIcon />
              <Box>
                <Typography variant="subtitle2">opacity</Typography>
              </Box>
              <Slider
                aria-label="Default slider"
                valueLabelDisplay="auto"
                onChange={updateSlider}
                value={settingForm.values.opacityValue}
                name="opacityValue"
                step={0.1}
                max={1}
              />
            </Box>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={12} md={2}>
            <Box display="flex" justifyContent="flex-end">
              <Button
                color="primary"
                variant="contained"
                size="large"
                onClick={settingForm.handleSubmit}
              >
                ADD
              </Button>
            </Box>
          </Grid>
          <h2>you picked {newHexCodes}</h2>
        </Grid>
      </CardContent>
    </Card>
  );
```

[CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-field-de9p8d?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: How does a single color have "contrast"?

Comment: mean, can you tell me which way you are saying this

Comment: What I mean is that "contrast" is generally about an overall image. For a single color,  I don't know how "contrast" means anything.

Comment: I mean opacity of color not contrast updated code

Answer (score 1):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_model

It is called RGBA and you use 8 chars instead of 6.

Example: #ff000055

Comment: can you give the range last two values like in opacity we give 0.1 - 1 in between for this example how can I know lower to higher

Comment: @devdeveloper it's 0 - 255, or in hex 0 - FF

Comment: I am asking about opacity I have one opacity slider I need to update hex according to selected opacity, not about hex color code range

Comment: it's possible to use the slider opacity value in last this example last of "55" example #ff000055

Comment: @devdeveloper it is hex so `00`  is min and `ff` is max. Translate your slider values to those.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert `0-1` range to `0-255` range and then convert the `0-255` range to `HEX`, then append this value to your color string.